# Using gnuplot remotely from Mac

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I have a Mac with OS 10.11.1, from which I ssh, using Terminal (with -Y option) to a remote cluster. Once on the cluster, I want to use gnuplot to generate a plot on a window that I would expect to open on my Mac, but it doesn't.

I have no problem doing it from another Mac with OS 10.8.

Why doesn't the plot window appear on the newer Mac?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `gnuplot` with X11? If so, you need XQuartz installed on the Mac that is doing the display. You also need to set DISPLAY on the Mac that is running `gnuplot`.

Comment: That was it, XQuartz wasn't installed. Thanks a lot!